# Put topic name first and username second in Activity tab

Tags: feature-request, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23?tab=activity for example. Currently the editor's name goes first and then the edited topic. I don't think people look for editor names first, rather the topics, and then comes the editor's name.

Comment: I hope this nice idea doesn't get lost. In case anyone needs another example: http://stackoverflow.com/ (first there are the question titles, then the names of the askers).