# Link Docs activity tab to the actual action

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

To check out what robo-reviews have wrought in the R tag, I'm looking at [the activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r?tab=activity).

Unfortunately, none of the links here are terribly informative. For each "edit" action in this list, I have to click three times to actually view the edit. What gives?

More generally, I think that [the display in the activity tab need improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328797/1191259). Really, I'd like to see the text of the edit summary here. Amazingly, even that info is buried three clicks deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the next build, there will be a "view change" link alongside every activity that goes directly to the proposed change behind it.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion:

> [<>] [HypnoGenX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6082538/hypnogenx) edited [50 State Maps and Advanced Choropleths with Google Viz](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95972) ([view topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1372/introduction-to-geographical-maps/5337/50-state-maps-and-advanced-choropleths-with-google-viz))
>
> 1 hour ago • *Fixed typo.*

Comment: Thanks, yup, that's the info I'd expect to see.