# Add a timestamp to the approved changes interface

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-dashboard

In Documentation under the tag dashboard there is a section where you can view all of the recent approved changes. For example, [this is that section for the Java tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java?tab=proposedchanges&subtab=approved).

This is important because it is essentially the location where you would want to be for auditing material that is changing in the tag ([a topic of concern lately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334877/1026459)).

However, when looking at the list of changes, there are no timestamps. Sure, you can click through but that is very tedious when that information is already available to the view, especially considering that many of the items may have already been audited by you.

Please add in a timestamp to the approved changes list.

[image]

Perhaps it could read "edit [timestamp] by [name] [rep]".

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java?tab=activity?

Comment: @JF - No, that is far too inefficient. You can see the activity, but actually reaching the edit or viewing the review takes many clicks.

Comment: There’s a [feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334628/5244995) for that FYI.