# Proposed changes notifications not being sent

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, notifications

Recently I subscribed to the Immediate setting for proposed changes to JavaScript Documentation in order to try to assist in making sure low quality doesn't live long after being robo reviewed.

[image]

However, the notifications only show up while I am active. I went inactive yesterday and then when I came back today there had been several proposed changes overnight. Yet, when I navigated to Stack Overflow there was no notification of them. Then, as I interacted with the site, [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/98082?filter-tags=javascript) showed up.

After reviewing it, this prompted me to wonder if no other changes had occurred since I was last active which led me to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97827?filter-tags=javascript that I had not seen yet and *never* received in my inbox.

It should be where the sad empty red circle is

[image]

Comment: "Sad empty red circle" I see a grey line in there, it can't be that sad and empty

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - A mere glimmer is all the grey line represents in the desolate wasteland occupying the space destined to hold a proposed change.

Comment: I had noticed this myself, but there was only one change since I last looked on the tag I'm subscribed to, and I wasn't 100% sure if it was there before I set the notification. I am, however, 90% sure it wasn't there before I set the notification. I was waiting for more proof before I posted my own bug.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here isn't so much that you have to be active, it's that "immediate" isn't actually immediate.

There's a scheduled task that runs every two minutes or so, and it looks at proposed changes that are *still active* at that time, then aggregates them into a notification (so you'd see "tag: 'X' and Y other changes need review" as opposed to one notification per change). So basically if a proposed change is submitted for review *and* reviewed within that time, no notifications will be generated.

In the interests of not spamming people with truly immediate notifications that they may not be able to even act on, we're changing the copy on the notification settings to be mildly more clear about the fact that they're not truly immediate:

> [image]

Comment: Can we please still have a way to see them all? I'm currently a bit bored of checking each day anew if I have missed some proposed changes... As noted in the OP: _in order to try to assist in making sure low quality doesn't live long after being robo reviewed._

Comment: The entire reason I subscribed to Immediate was to review everything being robo reviewed with the understanding that things often get through without being able to action them. There is a need to essentially double check the approved changes. There are not that many changes per day, at most I think I have seen 7 in 1 day in the JavaScript tag looking back through the log - getting 7 notifications after subscribing to immediate is what I would expect. Not getting notifications of any sort after choosing immediate is *broken* in my opinion, and requires manual inspection.

Comment: Changing the wording to "it doesn't work" is not a fix.

Comment: @TravisJ It was never intended to be truly immediate, so the wording was wrong. Hence the [status-bydesign]. There's also the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history) tab in Review that shows everything.

Comment: @AdamLear - The feature is fatally flawed if that is the case, as it *also* does not notify of "new" changes ever. It only notifies of "un-handled" changes.

Comment: Given that we're notified of edits to our posts even if the edit has already been approved in review, this doesn't make much sense.  It's obviously possible to notify about all changes rather than pending changes.  Add a toggle for "pending vs everything" and make people opt in if you're concerned about volume.

Comment: @davidism You're only notified on *substantial* edits to your posts. There is no ownership in Documentation, for one thing. For another, anything is theoretically possible. :) This notification code isn't the same as the code that sends out edit notifications and it was designed differently. My goal here was to clarify the current implementation. If there's a need for more... we can discuss that/reconsider. Personally, I think we can do better for monitoring robo reviewers than having someone get a notification for literally every thing.

Comment: Notifications in Docs are meant to encourage action, not monitoring of completed actions.

Comment: Ok, substantial edits. The point was about the notification versus the state of the edit, not the type.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I meant that you're still not getting a notification for *every* edit.

Comment: Because of the robo reviewing, I essentially *never* receive notifications, regardless of the setting. There is definitely a need here. This is supposed to be the interface for users that are involved in the tag, and at present it is not working, which means that Docs is missing out on a lot of signal from experienced users.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm sympathetic to the robo reviewer issue, but I'm not so sure notifications are the solution there. I'll think on it more, though, and bring it up for more discussion on our next team call.

Comment: @TravisJ This change should help with checking up on completed reviews: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334628/link-docs-activity-tab-to-the-actual-action